# mPDF: how to remove setHeader() & setFooter() borders

Tags: php, mpdf

i have a mPDF report on my system and in the report, it has a header and footer where i use `$mpdf->setHeader();` & `$mpdf->setFooter();` to set the header and footer. but it displays a bottom border for header and top border for footer. can anyone help me how to remove this?

heres the image:

[image]

Here's my Code:

```
$mpdf=new mPDF('','LETTER-L','','',35,35,60,25,10,10);
//left margin, right margin, body, top margin,top margin,bottom margin, 

/*HEADER Monthly Accomplishment Report*/
$mpdf->SetHeader('Sample');


/*FOOTER xMonthly Accomplishment Report*/
$mpdf->SetFooter('Sample');




//==============================================================
//=====================FILE DESCRIPTION=========================
//==============================================================
$mpdf->SetTitle('Monthly Accomplishment Report');
$mpdf->SetSubject('Report');
$mpdf->SetAuthor('sample');
$mpdf->Output('sample.pdf','I');
exit;
//==============================================================
//==============================================================
//==============================================================
```

Answer (score 13):

You could use those two mpdf properties instead:

```
$mpdf->defaultheaderline = 0;
$mpdf->defaultfooterline = 0;
```

Comment: use it before setFooter !

Answer (score 2):

I had a look at the documentation of the method [setHeader](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/setheader.html) and found that exists a `line` parameter :

> $line: specify whether to draw a line under the Header

You passed a `string` to the method but it **also accept an array of options**.

`$line` mentionned in the doc is not exactly a parameter of the method, rather a key of the configuration array.

So this code should accomplish what you look for, based on the documentation:

```php
$mpdf = new mPDF('','LETTER-L','','',35,35,60,25,10,10);
$headerFooterContent = 'Sample';
$oddEvenConfiguration = 
 [
    'L' => [ // L for Left part of the header
      'content' => '',
    ],
    'C' => [ // C for Center part of the header
      'content' => '',
    ],
    'R' => [
      'content' => $headerFooterContent,
    ],
    'line' => 0, // That's the relevant parameter
  ];
$headerFooterConfiguration = [
  'odd' => $oddEvenConfiguration,
  'even' => $oddEvenConfiguration
];
$mpdf->SetHeader($headerFooterConfiguration);
$mpdf->SetFooter($headerFooterConfiguration);
```

The `setHeader` and `setFooter` methods accept the same arguments (they are almost copy/pasted in the library).

I let you look further at the [specific part of the examples related to complex header configuration](https://mpdf.github.io/headers-footers/method-1.html#variant-5-arrayF) of mPDF.

Let me know if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of mpdf, you can use this:

```
$pdf->options['defaultheaderline'] = 0;
$pdf->options['defaultfooterline'] = 0;
```